# + and - on DC barrel connectors

Tags: dc, connector

I have a device which has a dc barrel jack with inside + and outside -. If I plug in a barrel connector which has 2 wires to connect to a DC voltage source (battery) how do I know which wire to connect to the positive terminal and which wire to the negative terminal?

Comment: use a continuity tester

Comment: Some Chinese Stuff has DC barrel  connector with Pos on the outside and Neg on the inside so be catreful .

Comment: Almost all stuff has +ve centre, -ve outside **EXCEPT** guitar effects pedals (as I found out to my surprise a few months ago)

Answer (score 0):

Not all cables have printed polarity indicators, so your best bet is to use a multimeter in continuity testing mode as mentioned by @jsotola.

Comment: How about this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoUHbf_bRxw